# Dynamic Calendar control

Tags: .net, asp.net, calendar, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5

How to generate dynamic calendar controls based on default calendar control's selectionchanged event?

Comment: Yes i want to generate a calendar control (asp.net) dynamically when one of calendar control (not dynamic but of asp.net) selection changed event is clicked